# Symfony - composer update - Dependency Injection Configuration class not found

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, bundle, symfony3.x, symfony-3.4

Our project is partly made of three bundles, two of them consist of a web backend application and an associated API consumed by our Customer's Frontend Single Page Application, the last one "CoreBundle" is where common resources live.

These bundles all have a DependencyInjection's (DI) bundle sub-directory but do not have Configuration class at all since none of them has any specific configuration. We use the DI component as suggested in the documentation, there is in theory no special case in this project that may influence the configuration loading mechanism.
This has been working well Until now (Symfony 3.3.2).

**In an intent of updating symfony/symfony from 3.3.2 to 3.4, composer post-install script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache generates 2 exceptions:**

> In Consistency.php line 337: Class Bundle\CoreBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration\Configuration not found
>     In Consistency.php line 285: Class Bundle\CoreBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration\Configuration not found

Exception trace:

```
Exception trace:
 Hoa\Core\Consistency\Consistency::autoload() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php:146
 Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass() at n/a:n/a
 spl_autoload_call() at n/a:n/a
 class_exists() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Resource/ClassExistenceResource.php:78
 Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\ClassExistenceResource->isFresh() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:351
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getReflectionClass() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Extension/Extension.php:84
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension->getConfiguration() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:63
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:39
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php:141
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:760
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:625
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:137
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:63
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/back-portal/src/Component/MultiApp/MultiAppConsoleApplication.php:35
 Component\MultiApp\MultiAppConsoleApplication->doRun() at /var/www/back-portal/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:129
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/back-portal/bin/console:31
```

Adding a Configuration class, with its `getConfigTreeBuilder()` method returning a new ("empty") Treebuilder instance, makes the exception point out another bundle. I did so for our three bundles and the exception now points out one of Sensio's own bundles instead.

> In Consistency.php line 337: Class Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration\Configuration not found …

Here are a few Composer warnings spawning before the exception gets thrown:

```
Dependency "symfony/polyfill-apcu" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
…
Package hoa/core is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use hoa/consistency instead.
Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.
```

*Executing `rm -rf var/cache/*` did not help.

Running only `bin/console cache:clear` throws this same exception.*

Now that our bundles implementation seem to not have anything to do with this issue, I have even less idea of what may be the root of the problem. That said, the line "`spl_autoload_call() at n/a:n/a`" looks strange …
May be some Symfony dependencies should be forced to some versions … ? (By the way [changelog](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v3.4.0-BETA1/CHANGELOG-3.4.md) did not provide helpful hint of a potential cause)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: This seems to be a problem using the abandoned package `hoa/core`.**

I might found a solution on this issue, as I faced the same problem that running `php bin/console` resulted in the error

> In Consistency.php line 337: Class Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration\Configuration not found …

after I upgraded my Symfony application from 2.8 to the latest 3.4 version.

I don't know your exact setup, but I also had the warning about the abandoned `hoa/core` package, so seeing your question here and the similarities between our setup, I got curious about that, because it states
`Use hoa/consistency instead.` while there is an error in a `Consistency.php` class. Aha!

So I simply took a lot at my `composer.json` and there was this outdated entry:

```
"hoa/regex": "~0.0"
```

that seemed to require the abandoned `hoa/core` package. 
For me, simply changing this to

```
"hoa/regex": "~1.0"
```

solved the problem. But as I don't know your exact `composer.json`, I don't know how your bundles depend on this package, so it might not be so easy to you to update to `hoa/consistency`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looking at packages (sub)dependencies, I finally figured out that the one causing the error was `phpmetrics/phpmetrics`. Simply bumping up the version `"^1.10" → "^2.3"` fixed my issue.